# breaking down multidimentional arrays in php

Tags: php

i have the following multidimensional array:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [array] => Array ( [0] => 6112010651088 [1] => Bill [2] => Choice ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [array] => Array ( [0] => 6702015707081 [1] => test [2] => data2 ) ) )
```

If you break the first array down using

```
foreach ($point1 as $val)
{
print_r($val);
}
```

you get:

```
stdClass Object ( [array] => Array ( [0] => 6112010651088 [1] => Bill [2] => Choice ) ) 
stdClass Object ( [array] => Array ( [0] => 6702015707081 [1] => test [2] => data2 ) )
```

so basically u have an array with 2 objects of array with 3 units of data each, how do i access this object stdClass array now, cos if i go $val[0] instead of $val i get

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($point1 as $val)
{
   echo $val->array[0].'<br/>';
}
```

will print:

```
6112010651088
6702015707081
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
$val->array[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference a property in an object, you use the `->` operator.

The object you've given us contains a property called `array`. You would therefore reference this as follows:

```
$val->array
```

This in turn contains the deeper level array data, which you can reference as a normal array.

Thus to reference the deeper array data in this structure, you would write it as follows:

```
$val->array[0]
```

Hope that helps.